# mdn Absolute positioning example

Tags: css

I am learning CSS from MDN and I came across something that I am not able to understand.The below link has mentioned "**In the example below, the ancestor div (box One) is positioned relative (so it becomes the nearest positioned ancestor) and box Two is positioned absolutely:**" but I am not able to figure out how box One is ancestor of box two. Please let me know if I am misunderstanding anything here.

The link : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning

Comment: yeah that is correct as to make any `div` position `absolutely` the parent of that `div` must be `relative` so the parent of `box2` is `box1` so the `box2` is positioned on the basis of `box1`

Comment: I guess Box1 is sibling of Box2. Not parent...

Answer (score 2):

I believe the documentation is rather confusing, the example is using siblings, but the positioning is based on the parent element's position which is positioned using relative/absolute/fixed

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Lets have some more views on it . If it is indeed wrong then I will submit correction request to Mozilla.

Comment: MDN is not just confusing, it is actually wrong. Box two is not positioned relatively to box one, but to the body. Box one just happens to be in the top left corner of the body.

Comment: I have reported bug https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1208958  lets see how soon they correct it :)